# Is it possible to retrieve the favicon of a url doing javascript client side scripting?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, favicon, yql

I'm guessing I would have to use JSONP for this but I don't know of any service that would let me do this.  Does anyone know of anyway of doing this?

Comment: Retrieve to do what? Just to show it, or to do something else? JSONP won't work as far as I can see, the icon resource can't return Javascript to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. First check if the favicon is declared in a meta tag and extract the URL. If there isn't a meta tag use the URL /favicon.ico. Then use `new Image(URL)` to manipulate/test the file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you asked, but the easiest way to retrieve a favicon is by using a servervice provided by Google:

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=en.wikipedia.org
```

Just edit it to point to the right domain.